# jqGrid with Related Tables in MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jqgrid

Good morning,

I'm going back to php and javasvript after a long time, and I used jqGrid pluging to create the grids. What I used well, to edit high and modify without problem. I can find the problem when I want to use a table with related data.

The table is the fees of some affiliates, which are related to the affiliates themselves. To edit use the jqgrid form. I tried to put a select, so they choose the affiliate, but I do not load the data.
I have given it many laps and I do not know what could be happening to me. To say that I am a little rusty. Sorry if there are very fat failures.

I put my code.

Index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
           jQuery("#tblCuotas").jqGrid({
           url:'cargaCuotas.php',
              editurl: "editCuotas.php",
           datatype: 'json',
           mtype: 'POST',
           colModel:[
              {
                 label: 'ID Cuota',
                 name: 'idCuota',
                 index:'idCuota',
                 width: 50,
                 key: true,
                 editable: true,
                 hidden: true
              },
              {
                 label: 'Num. Cuota',
                 name: 'NumD',
                 index:'NumD',
                 width: 50,
                 editable: true,
                 editoptions : { required: true, placeholder: "Número de Cuota requieredo"}
              },
              {
                 label: 'Num. Afiliado',
                 name: 'NumAfiliado',
                 index:'NumAfiliado',
                 width: 150,
                 editable: true,
                 edittype: 'select',
                 formatter:'select',
                 editoptions : { dataurl: 'afiliadosSelect.php' },
                 editrules : { required: true, placeholder: "Número de Cuota Afiliado"}
              },
              {
                 label: 'Nombre',
                 name: 'NOMBRE',
                 index:'NOMBRE',
                 width: 300,
                 editable: true
              },
              {
                 label: 'Cuota',
                 name: 'CUOTA',
                 index:'CUOTA',
                 width: 150,
                 editable: true,
                 editoptions : { required: true, placeholder: "Importe de la cuota requieredo"}
              },
              {
                 label: 'Mes',
                 name: 'MES',
                 index:'MES',
                 width: 120,
                 editable: true,
                 editoptions : { }
              },
              {
                 label: 'Año',
                 name: 'ANNO',
                 index:'ANNO',
                 width: 50,
                 editable: true,
                 editoptions : { }
              },
              {
                 label: 'Pago',
                 name: 'PAGO',
                 index:'PAGO',
                 width: 50,
                 editable: true,
                 edittype: 'select',
                 editoptions : { value: "Y:SI;N:NO" }
              },
              {
                 label: 'Forma Pago',
                 name: 'FormaPago',
                 index:'FormaPago',
                 width: 100,
                 editable: true,
                 editoptions : { }
              }

           ],   
              loadonce: false,
              width: window.innerWidth-20,
              height: window.innerHeight-150,
           pager: '#paginacion',
           rowNum: 50,
           rowList:[50,100,150],
           sortname: 'NumD',
           sortorder: 'asc',
           viewrecords: true,
           caption: 'CUOTAS'
        });   


        jQuery("#tblCuotas").jqGrid('navGrid','#paginacion',
           {edit:true,add:true,del:true},
           // options for the Edit Dialog

           {
              html5Check :  true,
              editCaption: "The Edit Dialog",
              recreateForm: true,
              checkOnUpdate : true,
              checkOnSubmit : true,
              closeAfterEdit: true,
              reloadAfterEdit:true,
              reloadAfterSubmit:true,
              errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                       return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
                   },
              buttons : [
                 {
                    side : "right",
                    text : "Afiliado",
                    position : "first",
                    click : function( form, params, event) {
                       alert("Custom action in search form");
                    }
                 }
                 ]
                  },


           // options for the Add Dialog
           {
              closeAfterAdd: true,
              html5Check : true,
              recreateForm: true,
              errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                 return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
              }
           },
           // options for the Delete Dailog
           {
              errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                 return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
              }
           });

     });


  </script>
```

afiliadosSelect.php:

```
 <?php
    include "../class/tAfiliados.php";

   echo '<script>alert("Custom action in search form");</script>';
   $oAfiliado = new tAfiliados(1, 0, 1, 1);
   $respuesta = $oAfiliado->selectAfiliados();


    echo $respuesta;
?>
```

tAfiliados.php:

```
    <?php

    include 'tMySQL.php';



class tAfiliados
{

   public function selectAfiliados()
   {
      $oMySQL = new tMySQL();

      if ($oMySQL->bConnect)
      {
         $cSQL ="SELECT COUNT(*) AS cuantos FROM afiliados WHERE borrado=0";   
         $this->fila = $oMySQL->countQuery($cSQL);
         $this->cuantos = $this->fila['cuantos'];

         $query = "SELECT idAfiliado, NumAfiliado, NOMBRE FROM afiliados WHERE borrado=0 ORDER BY NOMBRE"; 
         $result = $oMySQL->GetQuery($query);

         $response ='<select>';
         $i=0;
         while( $i <= $this->cuantos ) {
            $response .= '<option value="'.$result[$i]['NumAfiliado'].'">'.$result[$i]['NOMBRE'].'</option>';
            $i++;
         }
         $response .= '</select>';

      }

      $oMySQL->Close();   
      return $response;
   }
}

?>
```

Greetings and many thanks.

Comment: How look the response from the server for the select? You can use the console in order to see the response from theserver

Comment: When I directly call "affiliatesSelect.php", it shows me a combo with all the affiliates. But from the grid, it does not do anything. It does not show data or error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove this line from your code:

```
echo '<script>alert("Custom action in search form");</script>';
```

This causes problem to load the data. The data should contain only html data and nothing more.

This echo causes the data to fail to load into the grid.

UPDATE:

Sorry, Just now I jhave look at your code. The JavaScript is case sensitive.

Please replace

```
editoptions : { dataurl: 'afiliadosSelect.php' },
```

With

```
editoptions : { dataUrl: 'afiliadosSelect.php' },
```

**UPDATE2**

I have prepared a demo with your settings and it works fine. Here [is the link](http://guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/support/avielo/). Please check if your path to afiliadosSelect.php is correct in the related toy your file where the grid is.  In this case you should get in console a error.

Comment: It's a forgotten test line, but before it did not work anymore. I have deleted this line of code and it does not work. :-(

Comment: Look at the debug console in the browser if the response is coming to the grid and if yes what is happen. Usually to lunch the debug console pres F12 after you load the page and then try to open the edit form and see what is happen.

Comment: It shows nothing. It appears in white. It's as if he did not call the file 'affiliatesSelect.php'.

Comment: Look at my updated answer. You have a typo - your write **dataurl** - should be **dataUrl**

Comment: I have changed 'dataUrl' and it remains the same.

Comment: I have tried to rewrite the code and everything works fine. It must have been some badly written character. Thank you very much for your help. A greeting.